# SQL Server: birthday Leap year

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to retrieve a data based on:

Sql query to display list of employees  whose name start with letter  ‘f’ and year of birth should be leap year.

tried uisng function, if only for the leap year: ( help from one of my peer)

```
CREATE FUNCTION leapyear (@year INT)  
RETURNS INT  
AS  
BEGIN  
RETURN(IIF(DATEPART(dd,(EOMONTH(CONCAT(@year,'0201')))) = 29,1,0))
END
```

But when we need name along with year then what to do.

More over besides using function is there any simple way to do it( Involving less code)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided enough details in your question as to how you are storing year of birth. I am just trying to help you to provide this condition to check if the year is a leap year:

```
CASE WHEN (@YEAR % 4 = 0 AND @YEAR % 100 <> 0) OR @YEAR % 400 = 0 THEN 'LEAP YEAR'
```

And also add the condition that `Name like 'f%'` to display list of employees whose name start with letter ‘f’

Something like this:

```
select * from employees
where ((@YEAR % 4 = 0 AND @YEAR % 100 <> 0) OR @YEAR % 400 = 0)
and Name like 'f%'
```